# How to join three many-to-many models with a double-join condition

Tags: django, django-models

I want to execute this query of three models/tables:

```
-- get all items that don't have a status for this member
SELECT  i.*
FROM
 mock_item i
 LEFT JOIN mock_itemstatusmember ism ON i.id = ism.item_id AND ism.member_id = 2

WHERE
 ism.id IS NULL
```

Here are how my models look:

```
from django.db import models

# think status as a status
class Member(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Status(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    no = models.SmallIntegerField()

class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.ManyToManyField(Status, through='ItemStatusMember')
    member = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through='ItemStatusMember')    


class ItemStatusMember(models.Model):
    """
    Table that keeps job statuss information for a user.
    Tides Items with Members with Statuss
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

And their database sample data:

```
mysql> select *  from mock_member;
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Stefan |
|  2 | Alex   |
|  3 | Diana  |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *  from mock_status;
+----+---------+----+
| id | name    | no |
+----+---------+----+
|  1 | Pending |  1 |
|  2 | Success |  2 |
+----+---------+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *  from mock_item;
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | My first item  |
|  2 | My second item |
|  3 | My third item  |
+----+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *  from mock_itemstatusmember;
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| id | status_id | member_id | item_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |         1 |       1 |
|  2 |         2 |         1 |       2 |
|  3 |         1 |         2 |       1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need this, with the ORM, and NOT with the raw SQL query facility from the ORM to get all items that don't have a status for this member.

The SQL query at the beginning of the question does this, so it's important to have the

```
AND ism.member_id = 2
```

condition as a second condition to the left-join part, instead of moving into `where`, which I know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q    
Item.objects.filter(~Q(member__id=2))
```

Comment: Hi, the query generated by your filter, moves the member_id = 2 condition in where clause. So it gives zero results. The query that I've written in the question, gives two results (item_id = 2 and item_id 3).

Comment: After realising that I had not gotten my points lol, I'm trying to reach that 500 mark,I decide to take a look back at my answer. After taking a better look at your SQL I noticed that what you were trying to do in my own words is to get items that don't belong to member 2. I've update my code to do just that. However, the actual ORM generated SQL will differ from yours. If you just want the result it should be fine, but if you want the underlying SQL to be the same then It's of no use to you.

Comment: yup, works like a charm :) It's kind of magical how it knows to do exactly what I need with such a short syntax. I looked at the query, it does subselects, it looks like this: SELECT `mock_item`.`id`, `mock_item`.`name` FROM `mock_item` WHERE NOT ((`mock_item`.`id` IN (SELECT U1.`item_id` FROM `mock_itemstatusmember` U1 WHERE (U1.`member_id` = 2  AND U1.`item_id` IS NOT NULL)) AND `mock_item`.`id` IS NOT NULL))
   - I also can adapt for fetching items in a status for a user, which was the next step: q = Item.objects.filter(Q(member__id=2 ) & Q(status__id = 1))  . Thanks !